# Using VIM command on all open files

Tags: bash, vim, vi

I have a list of files i've opened in VIM using this command:

```
vim `cat list.txt`
```

I'm looking to run this command on all open files:

```
:99,104 norm i#
```

(from lines 99 to 104, insert a comment "#") <--simple, works

When I run the above command to insert it works as expected on the current file. How do I get VIM to run the exact same command on all open files? I tried `:argdo`, `:windo`, `:bufdo` but didn't have any luck.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I guess [`bufdo`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#%3abufdo) would work, if you have [`set hidden`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27hidden%27) (to allow `bufdo` to change buffers without saving) before:

```
:set hidden
:bufdo 99,104 norm i#
```

Then save all files with `:bufdo! w` or `:wa`.

(Note: `set hidden` could be replaced with [`set autowrite`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27autowrite%27) as well.)

Comment: Thanks, I missed the ":set hidden". Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

I think sed would be a better option if you can use it. sed is a command line editor rather than an interactive editor like vim.

```
sed -i '99,104s/^/#/' list of files
```

Comment: `sed` is a _stream_ editor. If you want a (genuine) _text_ editor that can be driven from a script or the command line, there's `ed` and `ex`.

Answer (score 2):

Because you've supplied all files as arguments, `:argdo` is the correct command. (Unless you open other files, `:bufdo` would work, too.) If you don't want to `:set hidden` (as indicated in the other answer), you have to immediately persist the buffer via `:update`. Because you're using a `:normal` command, you have to enclose it in `:execute` to be able to concatenate another Ex command:

```
:argdo 99,104 execute 'norm i#' | update
```